# Появляется непонятная ошибка

Tags: python

Изучаю python книге Майкла Доусона "Программируем на Python".
В шестой главе нужно написать игру "Крестики - нолики" . 
Я написал такую программу :

```
import random
#крестики-нолики
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "ничья"
NUM_SQUARES = 9
def main():
    return 0
def display_instruct():
    print ("""
    0 | 1 | 2
    ---------
    3 | 4 | 5
    ---------
    6 | 7 | 8
    """)
def ask_yes_no(question):
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input (question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response
def pieces():
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Кто будет ходить первым?\n")
    if go_first == "y":
        print ("Ваш ход!")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print ("Начинаю")
        human = O
        computer = X
    return computer, human

def new_board():
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    print ("\n\t", board[0], " | ", board[1], " | ", board[2])
    print ("\t", "-----------")
    print ("\n\t", board[3], " | ", board[4], " | ", board[5])
    print ("\t", "-----------")
    print ("\n\t", board[6], " | ", board[7], " | ", board[8])
    print ("\t", "-----------\n")

def legal_moves(board):
    moves =[]
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves

def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
    return None

def human_move(board, human):
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Ваш ход ", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print ("\nПоле уже занято.\n")
    print ("OK.")
    return move

def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    board = board[:]
    print ("Ход на поле номер", end=" ")
    for move in legal_moves (board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print (move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in legal_moves (board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print (move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    # полная проверка ходов
    legal_moves = a
    help = len(a)
    used_fields_1 = []
    used_fields_2 = []
    for i in help :
        for move in legal_moves (board) : # Здесь ошибка
            board[move] = computer
            if winner(board) == computer:
                used_fields_1.remove (move)
                for i in used_field_1 :
                    board [i] = EMPTY 
                print (move)
                return move 
            used_fields_1.append (move) 
        for move in legal_moves (board) :
            board[move] = human
            if winner(board) == human:
                used_fields_2.remove (move)
                for i in used_fields_2 :
                    board [i] = EMPTY 
                print (move)
                return move 
            used_fields_2.append (move) 

def next_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X

def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print (the_winner, "побеждают\n")
    else:
        print ("Ничья")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print ("\nПобеда компьютера\n")
    elif the_winner == human:
        print ("\nПобеда игрока\n")
    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print ("\n Ничья")

def game():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)
    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)

game()
```

input ("\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")

Появляется ошибка из-за строки for move in legal_moves (board) . Я не понимаю что здесь произошло и как это исправить .

Comment: Текст ошибки напишите.

Comment: А, все вижу, вы несколькими строками выше перезаписали эту функцию каким-то значением, а потом пытаетесь это значение вызывать как функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Конфликт имен: функция  `legal_moves (board)` переписана локальной переменной здесь:

```
# полная проверка ходов
legal_moves = a
```